# Using SAS to copy a text file

Tags: sas

Is there a SAS procedure / function which can be used to copy a *text* file from one location to another?

Of course this can be achieve using OS commands (%sysexec copy) but surely there must be an OS-agnostic way to do this?

From what I can tell by looking at the documentation, proc copy (or proc cport) only relate to SAS files..

Comment: This macro will do the job: https://core.sasjs.io/mp__binarycopy_8sas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SAS 9.4 and forward use the FCOPY function.  Use the recfm=n (n for none or binary) to perform a true copy.

```
filename src "path-to-src" recfm=n;
filename dst "path-to-dst" recfm=n;
%let rc = %sysfunc(FCOPY(src,dst));
%put %sysfunc(SYSMSG());
```

If the filerefs do not use the recfm=n option FCOPY will treat them as a text file and thus be affected by control characters and end of file markers.

Comment: Another benefit of using `recfm=n` even for text files is if a text file has long lines it would be copied in its entirety instead of what's within LRECL.

Comment: The only problem with this method is it assumes the target destination files already exists.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest method is something like:

```
 data _null_;
    infile 'c:\input.txt';
    file 'c:\output.txt';
    input;
    put _infile_;
 run;
```

The method presented by RawFocus will copy any file, in binary, one byte at a time from input to output. For a text file this isn't necessary and doing the above will copy the file one line at a time. You may have to be slightly careful with record lengths, I believe that the default record length is 256, so you may need to put an explicit

```
 lrecl=32767
```

option or similar on the `infile` statement, as in

```
infile 'c:\input.txt' lrecl=32767;
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems [Chris Hemedinger](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/06/17/how-to-use-sas-data-step-to-copy-a-file-from-anywhere/) has the answer!

```
/* these IN and OUT filerefs can point to anything */
filename in "c:\dataIn\input.xlsx"; 
filename out "c:\dataOut\output.xlsx"; 

/* copy the file byte-for-byte  */
data _null_;
  length filein 8 fileid 8;
  filein = fopen('in','I',1,'B');
  fileid = fopen('out','O',1,'B');
  rec = '20'x;
  do while(fread(filein)=0);
     rc = fget(filein,rec,1);
     rc = fput(fileid, rec);
     rc =fwrite(fileid);
  end;
  rc = fclose(filein);
  rc = fclose(fileid);
run;

filename in clear;
filename out clear;
```

Thanks Chris

Comment: Raw, you should now be able to mark your answer as correct - might want to as otherwise this looks like it's unanswered :)  Also, I'd suggest you add this to the FAQ as it's a commonly needed concept (IMO, for a very limited definition of 'common').

Comment: Done - thanks Joe - I kinda wanted to make sure there were no 'better' answers first though, as would feel kinda cheeky marking my own answer 'correct' if this was the case!  Also - what are you referring to by 'add this to the FAQ'?

Comment: I was referring to an inaccurate understanding of how FAQ worked :)